# Find the sum of consecutive whole numbers w/o using loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math

I'm looking for a method to do calculations like:

```
function sumIntegerUpTo(number) {
  return 1+2+3+...+number;
}
```

If you pass `number` as `5` function should return the sum of `1+2+3+4+5`. I'm wondering if it's possible to do without loops.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Some_summations_of_polynomial_expressions It's the fourth one.

Comment: @FK82 - Not it isn't. You need to read the question again.

Comment: @Simon: You're right, **sum** not **product**. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function sumIntegerUpTo(number) {
    return (1 + number) * number / 2;
}
```

I can think of two easy ways for me to remember this formula:

- Think about adding numbers from both ends of the sequence: 1 and n, 2 and n-1, 3 and n-2, etc. Each of these little sums ends up being equal to n+1. Both ends will end at the middle (average) of the sequence, so there should be n/2 of them in total. So sum = (n+1) * (n/2).
- There are as many number before the average (which is (1+n)/2) as there are after, and adding a pair of numbers that are equidistant to this average always results in twice the average, and there are n/2 pairs, so sum = (n+1)/2 * 2 * n/2 = (n+1)/2*n.

You can fairly easily extend the above reasoning to a different starting number, giving you: sum(numbers from a to b, inclusive) = (a+b)/2*(b-a+1).

Comment: This misses the line that attributes this formula to Carl Friedrich Gauss.

Answer (score 8):

Of course it is!

```
1+2+3+...+n = n * (n+1) / 2
```

Comment: nico is right! You better use a mathematical function wherever possible because they represent a shorter way to some complex calculation which otherwise will require loops and/or recursion.

If you need high performance in a calculation, try to find it in a mathematical function as the above!

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use a recursive approach - which here is redundant given there is a simple formula! But there is always something cool and magical about recursion!

```
function addToN(n)
{
    if(n==0) return 0;
    else return n + addToN(n-1);
}
```

Edited to deal with 0!

Comment: Pass 100000 to that and enjoy :)

Comment: I think the enjoyment is more in writing it and thinking about the magic rather than watching it do its thing! :)

Comment: this is awful... such an easy mathematical function should not be calculated with recursion. huge performance hit with large number parameter!

Comment: @ilip-fku: I was being ironic... I'm not gonna test it, but having 100000 levels of recursions will just freeze your browser and make your users angry :)

Comment: Oh I agree with that completely! I mentioned it more for the educational value than anything else

Comment: Your function fails for zero.

Comment: +1 for thinking outside the box... As others complain, this solution certainly wouldn't make sense in real life, but this type of reasoning could lead to good solutions to other problems.